# Embed CSS and JS into specific Laravel view / blade template

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm just getting started with Laravel and purchase a template from codecayone. Everything is working perfect only one thing:

- The template use config/custom.php to define css/js file for each view.

```
<?php


return [
    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'PriPor'),
    'public' => [
        'favicon' => 'media/img/logo/favicon.ico',
    'global' => [
      'css' => [
        'assets/css/app.css',
        'assets/css/vendor~demo_form_editors.css'
      ],
      'js' => [
        'assets/js/vendor~app~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_add_product~demo_calendar~demo_datatable~dem~699a60a5.js',
        'assets/js/vendor~app~demo_form_editors.js',
        'assets/js/app.js',
        'assets/js/vendor~demo_form_editors.js',
        'assets/js/demo_form_editors.js'
      ],
    ],
    'pagelevel' => [
      'css' => [
        'analytics_dashboard' => [ ],
        'ecommerce_dashboard' => [ ],
        'ecommmerce_product_detail' => [
          'assets/css/ecommerce.css'
        ],
        'ecommmerce_add_product' => [
          'assets/css/ecommerce.css',
          'assets/vendors/dropzone/dropzone.css'
        ],
        'ecommmerce_checkout' => [
          'assets/css/ecommerce.css'
        ],
        'jstree' => [
          'assets/css/vendor~demo_jstree.css'
        ],
        'image_cropper' => [ ],
        'sweetalert' => [ ],
        'toastr' => [
          'assets/vendors/toastr/toastr.min.css'
        ],
        'dropzonejs' => [
          'assets/vendors/dropzone/dropzone.css'
        ],
        'editor' => [
          'assets/css/vendor~demo_form_editors.css'
        ],
        'wizard' => [
          'assets/css/vendor~demo_form_wizard.css'
        ],
        'britechart' => [
        ],
        'data_table' => [
          'assets/vendors/datatable/datatables.min.css'
        ],
        'vector_map' => [
          'assets/vendors/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css'
        ]
      ],
      'js' => [
        'analytics_dashboard' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_chartjs~demo_widget~ecommerce.js',
          'assets/js/dashboard_analytics.js'
        ],
        'ecommerce_dashboard' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_chartjs~demo_widget~ecommerce.js',
          'assets/js/dashboard_ecommerce.js'
        ],   
        'calendar' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_calendar.js',
          'assets/js/demo_calendar.js'
        ],
        'kanban_board' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_dual_listbox~demo_kanban_board.js',
          'assets/js/demo_kanban_board.js'
        ],
        'chat' => [],
        'management.all-wallet' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_chartjs~demo_widget~ecommerce.js'
        ],
        'ecommmerce_products' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_chartjs~demo_widget~ecommerce.js'
        ],
        'ecommmerce_product_detail' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_chartjs~demo_widget~ecommerce.js',
          'assets/js/ecommerce.js',
          'assets/js/ecommerce_product_detail.js'
        ],
        'ecommerce_add_product' => [
          'assets/js/ecommerce.js',
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_add_product~demo_dropzone.js',
          'assets/js/demo_add_product.js'
        ],
        'ecommmerce_checkout' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_chartjs~demo_widget~ecommerce.js',
          'assets/js/ecommerce.js',
        ],
        'profile' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_chartjs~demo_widget~ecommerce.js',
          'assets/js/demo_chartjs.js',
        ],
        'dual_listbox' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_dual_listbox~demo_kanban_board.js',
          'assets/js/demo_dual_listbox.js',
        ],
        'jstree' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_jstree.js',
          'assets/js/demo_jstree.js'
        ],
        'image_cropper' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_crop_image.js',
          'assets/js/demo_crop_image.js',
        ],
        'sweetalert' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_sweetalert.js',
          'assets/js/demo_sweetalert.js'
        ],
        'toastr' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_toastr.js',
          'assets/js/demo_toastr.js'
        ],
        'dropzonejs' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_add_product~demo_dropzone.js',
          'assets/js/demo_dropzone.js'
        ],
        'editor' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_form_editors.js',
          'assets/js/demo_form_editors.js'
        ],
        'add-job' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_form_editors.js',
          'assets/js/demo_form_editors.js',
          'assets/js/demo/demo-select2ssssssssssssssss.js'
        ],
        'input_mask' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_input_mask.js',
          'assets/js/demo_input_mask.js'
        ],
        'select2' => [
          'assets/js/demo/demo-select2.js'
        ],
        'wizard' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_form_wizard.js',
          'assets/js/demo_form_wizard.js'
        ],
        'britechart' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_britecharts.js',
          'assets/js/demo_britecharts.js'
        ],
        'chartjs' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~dashboard_analytics~dashboard_ecommerce~demo_chartjs~demo_widget~ecommerce.js',
          'assets/js/demo_chartjs.js'
        ],
        'data_table' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_datatable.js',
          'assets/js/demo_datatable.js'
        ],
        'google_map' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_google_map.js',
          'assets/js/demo_google_map.js'
        ],
        'vector_map' => [
          'assets/js/demo_jqvmap.js'
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

It's working okay but not the part I added extra, for example:

```
'add-job' => [
          'assets/js/vendor~demo_form_editors.js',
          'assets/js/demo_form_editors.js',
          'assets/js/demo/demo-select2ssssssssssssssss.js'
        ]
```

I've tested:

- Add extra asset embed within the old key, for example: ecommerce_dashboard, ... -> it's worked and the file is embeded to the output HTML result.
- Add a new key: 'add-job', re-check if the array format is correct, clear all cache, but the files were not embeded. It didn't cause any error for the old key, but only the CSS/JS on the new key not get embeded.

default.blade.php file:

```
  {{-- Global Theme Styles (used by all pages) --}}
  @if(!empty(config('custom.public.global.css'))) 
    @foreach(config('custom.public.global.css') as $style)
      <link href="{{ asset($style) }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    @endforeach
  @endif  

  @if(isset($action) && !empty(config('custom.public.pagelevel.css.'.$action))) 
    @foreach(config('custom.public.pagelevel.css.'.$action) as $style)
      <link href="{{ asset($style) }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    @endforeach
  @endif
```

footer.blade.php template

```
@if(!empty(config('custom.public.global.js')))
  @foreach(config('custom.public.global.js') as $script)
      <script src="{{ asset($script) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  @endforeach
@endif
<script>
var jQuery = window.$;
</script>
@if(isset($action) && !empty(config('custom.public.pagelevel.js.'.$action)))
  @foreach(config('custom.public.pagelevel.js.'.$action) as $script)
      <script src="{{ asset($script) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

What should I do and where to debug this issue?

I'm expecting to add extra keys to this config/custom.php file to define new CSS/JS for each view/blade template based on my needs.

Comment: you can write manually without config like `<link href="{{ asset('assets/js/demo/demo-select2ssssssssssssssss.js') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` or try `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Cached config maybe? Did you `php artisan config:clear` after making changes?

Comment: I've tried to clear all types of cache as I can but nothing change.

Answer (score 1):

Your `'add-job'` is in `config('custom.public.pagelevel.js.add-job')`, and in default.blade.php it points to css: `config('custom.public.pagelevel.css.'.$action)`. If I understood correctly, then just change the paths or add:

```
@if(isset($action) && !empty(config('custom.public.pagelevel.js.'.$action))) 
    @foreach(config('custom.public.pagelevel.js.'.$action) as $script)
      <script src="{{ asset($script) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: I copied the wrong one, it should be in the footer with this:
```
@if(isset($action) && !empty(config('custom.public.pagelevel.js.'.$action)))
  @foreach(config('custom.public.pagelevel.js.'.$action) as $script)
      <script src="{{ asset($script) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  @endforeach
@endif
```
However, it didn't work too.

Comment: No matter I try on the css or js, it didn't embed the extra key I added.